# Disable background highlighting in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I hate having to ask these types of questions, but I accidentally turned some feature on a few weeks ago and I can't get it back off. Mainly, all my button code in any activity gets highlighted. I don't want that on, whatever it is. Can anyone help me?[image: this is what it's doing]

Answer (score 2):

go to :

```
File/settings/Editor/Colors & Fonts/Language Defaults
```

And change scheme to Default or Customize it...

Hope This help you...